# Vue - Interpolation inside attributes/using the shorthand

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am having an issue with compiling a `.Vue` file. 
I am running a SPA using Vue.js and Laravel.

I am currently trying to add below, to my `Home.vue`:

```
<ais-index app-id="{{ config('scout.algolia.id') }}" api-key="{{ env('ALGOLIA_SEARCH') }}" index-name="contacts">

    <ais-input placeholder="Search contacts..."></ais-input>
    <ais-results></ais-results>

 </ais-index>
```

However, that gives me this error:

```
- app-id="{{ config('scout.algolia.id') }}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
- api-key="{{ env('ALGOLIA_SEARCH') }}": Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
```

I have even tried adding the `:` before the attributes like this, as the error suggests:

```
<ais-input placeholder="Search contacts..."></ais-input>
<ais-results></ais-results>
```

But that gives me this error:

```
  - invalid expression: Unexpected token { in

    {{ config('scout.algolia.id') }}

  Raw expression: :app-id="{{ config('scout.algolia.id') }}"

  - invalid expression: Unexpected token { in

    {{ env('ALGOLIA_SEARCH') }}

  Raw expression: :api-key="{{ env('ALGOLIA_SEARCH') }}"
```

Comment: You can't use blade syntax in a vue file.  These are javascript files, not PHP files, you can't access Laravel's functions.

Comment: @Devon - any idea on how I can access env variables in my `Vue` file?

Comment: You'd have to create javascript variables.  You can't mix PHP and Javascript.  I don't know how you're loading your SPA, but you could create variables when the SPA is being loaded from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I finally figured it out.

According to [**Laravel's docs**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#environment-variables), we may inject environment variables into Mix by prefixing a key in your `.env` file with `MIX_`

I then define these `env variables` in my `.env` like this:

```
ALGOLIA_APP_ID=XXXXX
ALGOLIA_SECRET=YYYYY
MIX_ALGOLIA_APP_ID=XXXXX
MIX_ALGOLIA_SECRET=YYYYY
```

So, in my `Home.vue` file I have this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                query: '',
                angoliaAppId: process.env.MIX_ALGOLIA_APP_ID,
                angoliaAppKey: process.env.MIX_ALGOLIA_SECRET,

            };
        }
    };
</script>
```

And I can now access them like this:

```
:app-id="angoliaAppId" :api-key="angoliaAppKey"
```

Bonus info:

I did read the Laravel docs before asking this question here, and I also added the `MIX.` variables to my `.env` file.

However, you need to re-compile npm. Using `npm watch` does not catch these changes. So you must use:

`npm run dev` or `npm run production`

Comment: Interesting, I've never seen that before.  Might be good for future readers if you link to the docs where it talks about mix including env variables.